# How to avoid Sed changing the file format?

Tags: linux, sed, utf-8, ascii

I was trying to use a sed file to preprocess a file, but the output from sed seems to change the format.  How should I avoid it?

```
file A.txt
A.txt UTF-8 Unicode English text, with very long lines

sed -f process.sed < A.txt > B.txt

head -2 process.sed
#!/bin/sed -f
s/[‘’"“”•·・、。《》™®\.★☆]\\[a-z\-]\+ //g

file B.txt
Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text, with very long lines, with LF, NEL line terminators
```

Because B.txt is not encoded UTF-8, I cannot do following processing.

```
vim B.txt
è·¯æ<98><93>æ<96>¯ Âç½<97>å¾·é<87><8c>æ ¼æ<96>¯ //è·¯æ<98><93>æ<96>¯Â·ç½<97>å¾·é<87><8c>æ ¼æ<96>¯ ]
```

Comment: I don't _think_ `sed` supports Unicode... what is it you're trying to do? (please include the full content of `process.sed`)

Comment: What are your `LC_ALL` / `LANG` / `LANGUAGE` environment variables set to?

Comment: @Attie I'm trying to remove all the Chinese punctuation symbols with tags.

Comment: @Attie  like ''This is a 、/DunHao punc" --> "This is a punc".  But only remove punctuations with tags

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that sed's regexp engine doesn't see your input file nor your `[…]` match as a list of Unicode characters; instead it sees each of them as multiple independent bytes. For example, it sees `•` as three bytes `\xe2 \x80 \xa2` and tries to match each of them individually against `[ \xe2 \x80 \x98 \xe2 \x80 \x99 \x22 \xe2 \x80 ... ]`.

So in the example you've shown in your post, the regex only matches and deletes the last byte of each punctuation character, but leaves the other 2 still there. That's what gives you an invalid (non-UTF-8) output file.

With GNU sed (tested on 4.5), this can be avoided by making sure that the *system locale* (the $LANG or at least $LC_CTYPE environment variables) is set to an UTF-8 compatible locale. For example:

```
$ export LANG='C'
$ echo '‘test’ “test”' | sed 's/[“”•]/X/g'
XX�testXX� XXXtestXXX
$ echo '•_test' | sed 's/[•‡]_/X_/'
��X_test

$ export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
$ echo '‘test’ “test”' | sed 's/[“”•]/X/g'
‘test’ XtestX
$ echo '•_test' | sed 's/[•‡]_/X_/'
X_test
```

(The locale language does not matter. *Any* UTF-8 locale will work.)

If this does not work for you, avoid `[…]` completely and use `\(…\|…\|…\)` (or `(…|…|…)` in sed -r), which is a multi-character alternative and will work regardless of how those characters end up being interpreted.

```
$ export LANG='C'
$ echo '‘test’ “test”' | sed 's/\(“\|”\|•\)/X/g'
‘test’ XtestX
$ echo '•_test' | sed 's/\(•\|‡\)_/X_/'
X_test
```